# Complexity of a nested loop using Geometric Sum

Tags: time-complexity

I have this attached code:

```
i = n;
while (i >= 1)
  { 
      for (k = 1; k <= i; k++) 
      {
         S;
      }
      i = i / 2;
  }
```

Where S is some code that doesn't change i, k or n, and has a complexity of O(1).

I wish to find the complexity: O(?).

My solution:

At the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will do n iterations

At the second iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will do n/2 iterations

At the third iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will do n/4 iterations

At the fourth iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will do n/8 iterations

At the last iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will do 1 iteration

This is a geometric series. So I have calculated the sum of the series:

$1+...+\frac{n}{8}+\frac{n}{4}+\frac{n}{2}+n$

Using the formula I know:

$S_{n}=\frac{1\cdot (2^{\log n}-1)}{1}=n-1$

The problem is, this is wrong. ChatGPT gets approximately 2n. I got n-1 using the formula of sum of geometric series. This result makes no sense. I have used a ratio of 2, first element is 1 (going from back to start to fit the formula), and number of elements in the series is log n.

Comment: How can `1 + xi + ... + n` be `n -1`?

Comment: The sum of `1 + 1/2 + 1/4  + ...` is 2. So of course the sum of `n + n/2 + n/4 + ...` which is the same as `n * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 +...)` is 2n

Comment: Do you agree with me this is a geometric series ? Have I used the correct formula for the sum ? If so, it should give the same result.

Comment: I'm actually not sure about your second formula because my brain isn't capable of visualizing that expression right now. But if it leads to `n-1` it's obviously wrong, because how can a sum of a bunch of positive numbers including `n` be `n-1`.

Comment: I agree. That's why I am asking the question, I think it's wrong either :-)

Comment: In my comment I'm referring too [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1%2F2_%2B_1%2F4_%2B_1%2F8_%2B_1%2F16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF?wprov=sfla1) which describes the complexity of your algorithm.

Comment: Also see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) on the sum of a general geometric series in the form of `a + a*r^1 + a*r^2 + a*r^3 + ...` which is `a/(1-r)` (for `|r| < 1`.  This exactly describes your algorithm, ie in your case `a = n` and `r = 1/2`. Thus the sum is `n/(1 - 1/2)` which is `2*n`

Comment: Your latest comment reflect an infinite series, mine is finite. I do agree that for BIG n, it's approximately the same.

Comment: Well of course it's an infinite series, because if you are calculating the *O(?)* of an algorithm, you have, per definition, calculate the limit for n -> infinity ...

Comment: And if you have a finite series with `n == 2^i`, (ie `n` is a power of 2) it's also quite easy to see, that `1 + 2+ 4 + ... 2^(i-1) + 2^i == 2^(i+1) - 1`, which is the same as `2^(log(n) +1) - 1 == 2 * 2^log(n) -1` which is about (if you discard the `-1`) `2*n`

Comment: So now (after a cup of coffee) I also see the error in your formula: You have `2^(log(n))` instead of `2^(log(n) + 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using the formula I know:  = [1 ∙ (2<sup>log</sup>−1)] / 1 = −1

There is a mistake in the application of the [geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). You can easily see something is wrong in your conclusion, as surely  + /2 is already more than , so the sum could never be just −1.

> and number of elements in the series is log .

That's the source of the mistake. There is one more term.

Let's do this again, and start with the smallest term:

= 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + /2 +

= 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + ... + 2<sup>log<sub>2</sub></sup>

There are thus log<sub>2</sub> + 1 terms, not log<sub>2</sub> terms, and so using the known formula it becomes:

= 1 ∙ (2<sup>log<sub>2</sub> + 1</sup> − 1) / (2−1) = 2−1